Add reference with name to an unnumbered section
I have a main text with some chapters and then an unnumbered appendix. In my main text, I want to refere to my appendix with its full name like I do below with section 1 Main results. How can I do that? When I try, I just get the number of the appdendix, but I want the full name Appendix A instead.

% !TeX spellcheck = de_DE
% !TeX encoding = utf8

\documentclass[leqno, fleqn]{article}

% German ---------------------------------------
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% Manually change the name of chapters and subchatpters https://texdoc.org/serve/hyperref/0
\addto\extrasngerman{
    \def\sectionautorefname{Kapitel}
    \def\subsectionautorefname{Unterkapitel}
    \def\source{\small Quelle: }
}
\newcommand\harvardand{und}
\DeclareMathSymbol{.}{\mathord}{letters}{"3B}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
%---------------------------------------

% Other languages -----------
\usepackage{CJKutf8} 
\usepackage{alphabeta} 

%---------------------------------------
    
% References ---------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=authoryear,
            dashed=false,
            natbib=true,
            minnames=2,
            maxnames=2,
            mincitenames=1,
            maxcitenames=2,
            maxbibnames=99,
            uniquename=false]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}


\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{ 
  andothers = {et al.},
}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} 
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\begin{itemize}}
  {\end{itemize}}
  {\item}

  \renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\iffieldundef{doi}{\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}{}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}} 

    \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{month}}

\newcommand*{\iffinalmulticitedelim}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{multicitecount}}{\value{multicitetotal}-1}
}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{%
  \iffinalmulticitedelim
    {\addspace\bibstring{and}}
    {\addsemicolon}%
  \space}


% Packages ---------------------------------------
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{moresize}

% Packages for the table
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}



\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\usepackage{tipa}

%---------------------------------------
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\roman{equation}}
\newcommand{\pp}[1]{\phantom{#1}}
%---------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox,refcount}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Example sentences
\usepackage{gb4e} 
\noautomath 
\newcommand{\pref}[1]{(\ref{#1})} 

% Table
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand\setrow[1]{\gdef\rowmac{#1}#1\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\clearrow{\global\let\rowmac\relax}
\clearrow

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 

% Use source for each figure and refs for the sections
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\vspace{-10pt} \caption*{ Source: {#1}} }
\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}

\newcommand{\lightref}[1]{\autoref{#1} \nameref{#1}}


% Settings for captions
\captionsetup{skip=3pt}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space, 
         justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}
         
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,
              justification=raggedright,
              singlelinecheck=false}


% Set margins and page numbering
%---------------------------------------
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, a4paper,includefoot,includehead]{geometry} 
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{pgflibraryshapes}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    dot/.style={draw=black, fill=white, circle, inner sep=2pt},
    enum/.style={baseline={([yshift=-1em] current bounding box.north)}},
    base at/.style={baseline={(#1.base)}},
    no enum/.style={baseline=default},
}

\usepackage{amssymb} 

\newcommand{\PreserveBackslash}[1]{\let\temp=\\#1\let\\=\temp}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\centering}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedleft}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\PreserveBackslash\raggedright}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Main results}
\label{sec:Main}

I have a cool section called \fullref{sec:Main}. But I have an even cooler one called \ref{sec:AppendixA}. I also have \fullref{sec:AppendixA} and  \lightref{sec:AppendixA}, and also \nameref{sec:AppendixA}.

\section*{Appendix A}
\label{sec:AppendixA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix A} 
Cool stuff.

\end{document}


Have you tried just using /nameref{sec:AppendixA}? Using your MWE, when I do that I get the hyperref without having to define a more complex command. The SE link you refer to in the comment is quite old and hyperref must have evolved since.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}
\newcommand{\lightref}[1]{\autoref{#1} \nameref{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Main results}
\label{sec:Main}

I have a cool section called \fullref{sec:Main}. But I have an even cooler one called \ref{sec:AppendixA}. I also have \fullref{sec:AppendixA} and  \lightref{sec:AppendixA}, and also \nameref{sec:AppendixA}.

\section*{Appendix A}
\label{sec:AppendixA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix A} 
Cool stuff.

\end{document}



Hm, thanks. I get it to work in my example. However, in the real project that I have, I don't get it to work. I get the error "package hyperref: Suppressing empty link". For full- and lightref, I get "Abschnitt" (German: Chapter), but nothing more after that. For nameref, I get nothing at all.

@KGB91: you will need to provide a Minimal (non)Working Example then. It is not possible for us to troubleshoot code that we cannot see.

@While Wong, yeah, you are right. I have now updated with my whole permeable.

You could try this other way:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\nameref*{#1}}}
\newcommand{\lightref}[1]{\nameref{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Main results}
\label{sec:Main}

I have a cool section called \fullref{sec:Main}. But I have an even cooler one called \fullref{sec:AppendixA}. I also have \lightref{sec:AppendixA}, and also \nameref{sec:AppendixA}.

\appendix
\section*{Appendix A}
\label{sec:AppendixA}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix A} 
Cool stuff.

\end{document}

Let me know how it goes!

Thanks for that, but I have given a label to the main section already.

@KGB91 Oh I'm sorry, I didn't really pay attention. Does the updated code works instead or?

@Franceso I do not see any update?

@KGB91I wrote the code from scratch earlier, that's why I didn't carefully compare. Imma try to find a way. Sorry for the incovinience ._.

@KGB91 Try checking now and let me know!
